# App for setting up a certain series of alarms is only working in the Android Studio Emulator

Tags: java, android, apk, alarm, samsung-galaxy

My final goal is to easily activate and deactivate a certain series of 17 alarms in the clock app whenever necessary. Unfortunately, the app only offers the option to either deleting(!) all alarms at once or deactivating one by one. The same applies to every other app from the Play Store I have tried.

I think an acceptable workaround solution would be to delete all alarms with the mentioned functionality and re-implement the series of alarms programmatically as needed. So, I wrote a minimalist app in Android Studio that works perfectly fine in the emulator.

After building the debug APK, I transferred it on my smartphone and installed it without any errors. Now I am facing the problem that after starting my app only the first alarm is created. Does somebody have an explanation for this error. Thank you!

**MainActivity.java**

```java
package com.example.setalarms;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.AlarmClock;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
        String[] messages = {"alarm1","alarm2to16","alarm17"};
        int[] hours = {7,8,9};
        int[] minutes = {0,0,0};
        ArrayList<Integer> days = new ArrayList<>(
                Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
        );
    
        Intent[] intents = new Intent[messages.length];
    
        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM)
                    .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, messages[i])
                    .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hours[i])
                    .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minutes[i])
                    .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_DAYS, days)
                    .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, i != messages.length - 1);
            intents[i] = intent;
        }

        startActivities(intents);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SetAlarms"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Hardware / Software**

```
SAMSUNG Galaxy A3 (2017) SM-A320FL
Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1 Patch 1
Android 8.0.0 (Oreo)
Clock 7.0.92.7 (Galaxy Store)
```

Comment: I don't know exactly how `startActivities` works, but if it sends the whole Intents-array in once call to the clock app the clock app may just accept one intent and ignore the other (because the clock developers could not imagine that more than one entry is added at a time). Therefore I would try to send the Intents one-by-one (and may be wait a small time span between each call just to make sure).

Comment: @Robert Thank you for your answer. Your suggestion had actually been my first attempt, but resulted in the same problem. In the meantime, I found another [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sentryapplications.alarmclock), that offers a different but acceptable workaround that works for me, I think. Regarding my post, I'm sticking to the assumption that the problem is coming from my hardware.